# Failed to initialize a component: No owner specified for component markup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura, actionfunction

I have a screen flow that calls an action "refreshPage" to refresh page after updating record.

It was working fine for several months but recently it started to fail and give the following error message:

> Failed to initialize a component [No owner specified for component markup://c:refreshPage

I have searched this error message for the whole day but still cannot find any relevant discussion.

Below is my code for this component:

.cmp

```html
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions">
</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```js
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
    }
```

I also tried window.location.reload() and window.location.top.reload() in my controller but the error persists.

Any advice on what the error means or how the code can be fixed is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: We have the same issue and it started with the recent release. I've been looking through the notes, and haven't been able to conclude what changed to cause this issue.

Comment: I've marked this question as protected because so far this has only garnered "I have this problem too" responses, which is not a good fit with the StackExchange model. If you're having this problem too, the right things to do are to follow the question (so you get notified when there is an answer) and to raise tickets with Salesforce's official support channels (in the hopes they'll see a trend and maybe address it in one way or another).

Comment: My current idea is to try to update the aura's component API version. We do not get the error on sandboxes, only on production as of now

Comment: Having the same issue with a Flow (markup://c:showToast). I'm going to uplevel the API version from 53 to 57 and see if that helps mitigate. Will report back if it does!

Comment: API version upgrade did not fix this issue, just to close that thread out...

Comment: Same here, I tried updating the API version but still no luck.

Comment: KI: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000sc7iaAAA/flow-navigation-via-aura-component-throws-gack-no-owner-specified-for-component-markup

Comment: Thank you @CyberJus!
Will follow up the ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a case open with Support and this is now a known issue acknowledged by Salesforce:

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000sc7ia/flow-navigation-via-aura-component-throws-gack-no-owner-specified-for-component-markup

There is no workaround for it